# Firebase - Duplicate insertions to database

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have an activity with a registeration form, When a user successfully registers it creates a new child in my database and starts the login activity.

The problem is that the user can click the button multiple time and it'll create duplicate users, I tried disabling the button when he clicks it and enabling it after it creates the new user but it doesn't work..

My Code:

```
register_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String username = txt_username.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = txt_password.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email = txt_email.getText().toString();

        register_btn.setEnabled(false);

        if(username.length() < 3) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Username must be atleast 3 characters long!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            register_btn.setEnabled(true);
            return;
        }
        if(password.length() < 6) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Password must be atleast 6 characters long!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            register_btn.setEnabled(true);
            return;
        }

        if(!validateEmail(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "The email entered is invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            register_btn.setEnabled(true);
            return;
        }

        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> e : users.entrySet()) {
            Map<String, Object> user = (HashMap<String, Object>) e.getValue();

            if(user.get("username").toString().equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "This username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                register_btn.setEnabled(true);
                return;
            }

            if(user.get("email").toString().equalsIgnoreCase(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "This email already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                register_btn.setEnabled(true);
                return;
            }

            final String uid = randomUID();
            final int id = users.size() + 1;

            Map<String, Object> newUser = createUser(id, username, password, email);

            ref.child(uid).setValue(newUser);

            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Successfully registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            register_btn.setEnabled(true);

        }
    }
});
```

users is a Map that constantly gets updated whenever the /Users in my database changes

**EDIT:** I've edit the ValueEventListener so it will delete duplicates whenever the database updates, it delete's old duplicates but the new ones it does'nt:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        users = (HashMap<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        Map<String, Object> last_user = null;

        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> e : users.entrySet()) {
            Map<String, Object> user = (HashMap<String, Object>) e.getValue();
            if(last_user == null) {
                last_user = user;
                continue;
            }
            if(user.get("username").toString().equalsIgnoreCase(last_user.get("username").toString())) {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(user.get("id").toString());
                int lid = Integer.parseInt(last_user.get("id").toString());
                if(id < lid || id == lid) {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/" + e.getKey()).removeValue();
                }
            }

            last_user = user;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "The following error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, databaseError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select a uid for this user. So if he clicks on the button again, Firebase won't create another user, but will update it's value instead.

```
final String uid = ref.push().getKey(); //OR call for your randomuid() methodd if you prefer
register_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String username = txt_username.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = txt_password.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email = txt_email.getText().toString();

        register_btn.setEnabled(false);

        if(username.length() < 3) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Username must be atleast 3 characters long!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            register_btn.setEnabled(true);
            return;
        }
        if(password.length() < 6) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Password must be atleast 6 characters long!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            register_btn.setEnabled(true);
            return;
        }

        if(!validateEmail(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "The email entered is invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            register_btn.setEnabled(true);
            return;
        }

        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> e : users.entrySet()) {
            Map<String, Object> user = (HashMap<String, Object>) e.getValue();

            if(user.get("username").toString().equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "This username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                register_btn.setEnabled(true);
                return;
            }

            if(user.get("email").toString().equalsIgnoreCase(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "This email already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                register_btn.setEnabled(true);
                return;
            }

            final int id = users.size() + 1;

            Map<String, Object> newUser = createUser(id, username, password, email);

            ref.child(uid).setValue(newUser);

            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Successfully registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            register_btn.setEnabled(true);

        }
    }
});
```